# Rails: adding to last object if conditions met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, prawn

I've got a method that scans an HTML string and sort of formats it for prawnpdf:

```
def format_for_prawn(pdf, string, colour)
  body = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(string)
  result = body.xpath('./*|./text()')
  result.each do |breaker|
    if breaker.name == "h3"
      pdf.fill_color colour
      pdf.text breaker.text.to_s, :size => 16
      pdf.move_down 5
    else
      pdf.fill_color '#444444'
      pdf.text breaker.text.to_s, :size => 10, :leading => 1
      pdf.move_down 10
    end
  end
end
```

It works great for `<h3>`s. In the event that some mid-paragraph `<b>` (or similar) tags are found it starts a new paragraph because that's where Nokogiri broke the string--which is the correct behaviour.

How could I add the bolded string to the last `pdf.text` function instead of calling a new `pdf.text` which results in a new paragraph?

I thought about making an array out of it all but then it'll be out of order with the `<h3>`s.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to do a negative match :

```
body.xpath( './node()[not(self::b)]' )
```

Sadly, this would exclude `<b>` rather than ignoring it :

```
> body = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse %(<h3><b>foo</b></h3><h3>bar</h3>fooz<b>baz</b>whatever); true

> body.xpath( './node()[not(self::b)]' ).to_a
[
    [0] <h3>
  <b>foo</b>
</h3>,
    [1] <h3>bar</h3>,
    [2] fooz,
    [3] whatever
]
```

So, you'll have no choice but using a buffer, here : we can iterate through nodes first, to populate a buffer regarding if we should have a new line or not, then iterate this buffer to have your lines added to pdf :

```
buffer = []

body.xpath( './node()' ).each do |node|
  if %w[text b].include? node.name
    # add to previous line or create one
    buffer << [] unless buffer.count
    buffer.last << { node: node }
  else
    # set content and create a new line
    buffer << [ { node: node, title: node.name == 'h3' } ]
    buffer << []
  end
end

# Now, each first level item in buffer is a line,
# containing elements we just have to concatenate text of
# to pass to `pdf#text`
buffer.each do |line|
  text = line.map do |part|
    node = part[ :node ]
    inner = node.text.to_s
    # restore <b> tag if you want bold style in pdf
    node.name == 'b' ? "<b>#{inner}</b>" : inner
  end.join

  if line.first
    if line.first[ :title ]
      pdf.fill_color colour
      pdf.text text, :size => 16
      pdf.move_down 5
    else
      pdf.fill_color '#444444'
      # inline_format ensure basic html formating is used, <b> in our case
      # See http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text.html#method-i-text
      pdf.text text, size: 10, leading: 1, inline_format: true
      pdf.move_down 10
    end
  end    
end
```

Of course, all of this is considering you do not control original html. Else, you should place your text nodes inside `<p>` or something, and there would not be problems anymore.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughtful reply. Reasoning sounds good, I didn't know how to execute it. I do get an `undefined method 'text' for #<Hash:...` error on this line, though: `text = line.map { |node| node.text.to_s }.join`.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that this will never work. I can't format the text differently in the same line without ripping prawn apart. Back to the drawing board I guess. Inline formatting seems to work only with bold and nothing else

Comment: Yes, there an error, `map { |node| node.text.to_s }` should be `map { |part| part[ :node ].text.to_s }`. As for bold, I didn't realized you want to keep it (won't a html2pdf based solution like wicked_pdf be more appropriate, in that case ?), but you can take advantage of `:inline_format` option of prawn. Editing for all of that.

Comment: Thanks again, but now I get an `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` on the `if line.first[ :title ]` line. That makes my `buffer` blank, right?

Comment: Nope, that's just a getter. Problem was the blank arrays created when there was two non-b elements one after the other. Edited ; but please : do not just copy paste that code, the point is to get the idea.

Comment: Thanks _so much_ for your help. I think I'm understanding what's going on here now. Thank-you.